# Use Magento 2 translation (for example German) from CrowdIn

Tags: magento2, localisation

So [people are translating Magento 2](https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2).

How can I use the current translation from there in my project?

I can download a `source.csv` - but won't I need one file per module?

Comment: Barnabet's solution doesn't works for me. But for the **Italian** language I found this great solution (working with composer also): https://github.com/antoniocarboni/magento2-traduzione-italiana http://www.bitbull.it/blog/installare-la-traduzione-italiana-magento2/. Reading from the Github doc, there is a *Manually* installation section that maybe can be adapted for other langauges.. Hoping this can be useful for someone else (and hoping there will be a simpler/general solution to install any language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using this command from your project root:

```
bin/magento i18n:pack --mode=replace -d path/to/your/file/source.csv . de_DE
```

After that, use this command:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

All the translations will be applied.

Comment: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ';' in /home/foo/bar/workspace/example.de/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/I18n/Dictionary/Phrase.php(278) : eval()'d code on line 1
`

Comment: Might be an issue with the PHP7 i am using (https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Problem-with-i18n-translation-collection-command-PHP-Parse-error/td-p/24879)

Comment: I was able to use the workaround at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3303 - but it looks like the `source.csv` (for de_DE) is already rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download the language pack](https://marketplace.magento.com/splendidinternet-mage2-locale-de-de.html) from the magento marketplace (free).

Then you just have to follow the installation instructions from the README.md

> ## Installation
>
> - Alle Dateien nach `/app/i18n/splendid/de_DE/` kopieren
>
> Aus dem Magento-Root-Verzeichnis folgende Befehle aufrufen:

```
rm pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/js-translation.json
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/di
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello Good afternoon my friend

Did the procedures that you said just upgrading to the language pt_BR

But see in the image that the error is displayed

"Requested languages: pt_BR
File "/i18n/pt_BR.csv" does not exist> "

You have some information to correct this occurrence, because I intend to use this translation pack

http://pasteboard.co/1eIoZv6N.png

http://pasteboard.co/1eIsgplB.png

The strange thing is that when updating the page we see that was applied due translation

http://pasteboard.co/1eIMGoxK.png

Comment: Mmm... I'm learning too. I guess that this is happening because we're trying to use an independent file and not a language module.
I'm using my own module https://github.com/barbanet/magento2-language-es_ar 
I think that you'll need to create the language module and then apply the downloaded file.

Comment: Marcio, this is not an answer, please delete.