# Magento2: can't translate transactional email phrases

Tags: magento2, email-templates, localisation, email-translation

I'm trying to translate some custom transactional email templates but I have some problems.

In the templates (`mycustomtheme/Magento_Sales/email`), strings are the same of the default luma ones.
If I try to change the translation using theme translation (`mycustomtheme/i18n/xx_XX.csv`) nothing happens. What I think is that my theme can't override luma phrases.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html / http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99915/use-magento-2-translation-for-example-german-from-crowdin / http://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-translation/